# How can I prevent code from being treated as part of a paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

A project I'm working on has it such that each section begins with a a little diagram. What I want, however, is for it not to be treated as a part of the text.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}%
\section{Test}

\tikz{\draw[fill=black!30] (0,0) rectangle (10,5);}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

And here's the final results:

[image]

Now, if I just remove the space between the `tikz` command the the start of the paragraph, the indentation goes away. However, the diagrams are inserted with a macro, and I would prefer to not have such tight/fragile restrictions on white space between the command and the text (for one thing, it makes the code look ugly). I could make it a float, I suppose, but I don't want it to get moved around, counted in the TOC, be given extra padding, or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about creating your tikz macro like this?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rect}{%
  \tikz{\draw[fill=black!30] (0,0) rectangle (10,5);}
  \par\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

Then you get the same result whether you have

```
\rect
\lipsum
```

or

```
\rect

\lipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `\par` at the end of the `\tikz` line and remove the ugly space ;)

```
...
\tikz{\draw[fill=black!30] (0,0) rectangle (10,5);}\par
\lipsum
...
```